# Should machine-stitch and hand-baste as verbs have a dash?

Tags: grammar, verbs, dashes

I'm wondering if anyone knows the correct way to write the following compound verbs: machine-stitch and hand baste? I found that machine-stitch as a verb has a dash, logic would tell that hand-baste should also have a dash, but I can't seem to find anything on this in any dictionary and I've never seen it written with a dash. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Looking at Google Books, it appears that the verbs are not usually hyphenated ("Pin the strip or hand baste very securely" / "Hand or machine stitch the strip to the background fabric"). Use a hyphen (not a dash) for adjectives before a noun): *machine-stitched/hand-basted clothing*. I would not for predicate use: *The piece is machine stitched/hand basted.* Note that the OED does have *machine-stitch* as a verb.

Comment: Thank you so much! And yes, of course it's a hyphen, the word escaped me when I was typing :) This whole topic of compound words seems so confusing, I keep finding different spelling variations.

Comment: I would do different searches in [Google Books](https://books.google.com/) and see what the majority of British or American authors do. You can fine-tune searches there for everything or just books or magazines.

Comment: That's an awesome suggestion, I will be doing that, thank you!!

Comment: I think "hand-baste" is a compound, and hence should be written as a single word, in this case hyphenated. Note that a compound word is always a single word. If written as two separate words, it is not a compound but a syntactic construction, cf. "greenhouse" (compound noun) vs "green house" (syntactic construction).

Comment: @BillJ What about something like "Hand tighten the nut—do not use a wrench"?

Comment: @BillJ The OED has *hand stitch* but *hand-sew* as verbs under *hand*. Have we opened a worm-can?

Comment: [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/machine-stitch) lists only the hyphenated compound verb _machine-stitch_ for both US and UK usage. Lexico only lists the hyphenated verb. Although _hand baste_ is arguably a compound, and is unarguably similar in form and usage to _machine-stitch_, there only seem to be open-form examples on the internet. Compounds (lexemes obviously composed of shorter words by the process of compounding) exist in open, hyphenated, and/or closed forms. There are examples where all three spelling variants are in use (ink well/ink-well/inkwell ...).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'm familiar with the three forms for nouns, often with progression over time time: ink well to ink-well to inkwell, but I'm hazier on compound verbs--take my example above: "hand tighten only".  I don't see very many hyphenated machine-stitch's among the many in Google Books.

Comment: If I see "baste," I assume it will be by hand. / Depending on the sentence, it might be helpful to use the hyphen (*machine-stitch*) so the reader doesn't get the idea that we're talking about the noun "machine stitch," e.g. "You'll want to choose a different machine stitch for the border."

Comment: @DjinTonic I would say that "hand-stitch" and "hand-tighten are just as much compound verbs as "hand-sew" is. Other similar examples include ""tape-record" and "hand-wash". Note that if they are not written as single words, they are not compounds, but syntactic constructions. Dictionaries are, as usual, inconsistent about compounds - don't rely on them.

Comment: Thanks so much for everyone's input! I think we did in fact open a can of worms; there seems to be no single correct answer on compound verbs. I did find many instances of "hand-baste" hyphenated in Google Books. @aparente001 Basting can be done both by machine and by hand, so sometimes it's necessary to specify the method :) And now that you mention that a hyphen could be useful to differentiate from "machine stitch" as a noun, maybe "hand baste" doesn't need a hyphen precisely because there's no such noun as "a hand baste" ??

Comment: @Rimma - in my opinion, almost all the time, basting means stabilizing things by hand, as we have more control over what goes where basting by hand, and the basting thread is easier to remove.  (An exception would be when we want to put something together to prepare for a fitting.)  So I would just say *baste*, personally.  Also I personally don't care for *hand baste* without a hyphen -- that bothers me more than including the redundant "hand" in "hand-baste."

Comment: The question of a hyphen in verbs and noun is, save in a few well-defined cases, not answerable definitively. The progress of verbs and nouns is 1. separate words; 2. Hyphenated words; 3. One word. However, many words simply stick at the metamorphosis from 1 to 2, or 2 to 3 - I assume some vacillate between 1 and 3. It's how evolution happens.